# Convert JSON string to array in php?

Tags: php, json

I want to convert the following JSON string to array using PHP...

```
a:6:{
i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:31003200320082;s:7:"address";s:5:"test1";}
i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:83003500350087;s:7:"address";s:9:"test2";}
i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:41002800280012;s:7:"address";s:5:"test3";}
}
```

Please help me....

Comment: Try [`unserialize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) on your data.

Comment: Your string is not a json, but it is not serialized array also. Where did you get this output?

Comment: It is stored in mysql db by converting like this....

Comment: @Hardik4now Who stored this string in mysql db ?

Comment: I don't know actually I am new in oops in php.... I am very much confused for this one.... :( This project is not developed by me so I am not getting the right function to insert in db...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got solution to your problem:

1. The String you are using is not a JSON string, its actually a serialized array. So you will need to use the function [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) instead of json_decode.
2. You are not getting success with [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) because the serialized string you have is malformed. I have made some adjustments in the string use mine one and you will get success.

old malformed one:

```
a:6:{
   i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:31003200320082;s:7:"address";s:5:"test1";}
   i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:83003500350087;s:7:"address";s:9:"test2";}
   i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:41002800280012;s:7:"address";s:5:"test3";}
   }
```

new Corrected string:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";i:31003200320082;s:7:"address";s:5:"test1";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";i:83003500350087;s:7:"address";s:5:"test2";}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";i:41002800280012;s:7:"address";s:5:"test3";}}
```

Have a good day my friend.

Answer (score 2):

Try using

`json_decode($data,true)` to get the results in Array format

true is for converting to array, otherwise it will return as object

Comment: Thanks but, I have tried bro... Look this... $locations='a:6:{i:0;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:31003200320082;s:7:"address";s:5:"test1";}i:1;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:83003500350087;s:7:"address";s:9:"test2";}i:2;a:2:{s:2:"id";d:41002800280012;s:7:"address";s:5:"test3";}}';
$resultLocations=json_decode($locations,TRUE);
print_r($resultLocations);

Comment: right , so first you need to correct JSON string otherwise it will keep on throwing error

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Best way:

1. Store the string in a PHP variable:

   $jsondata = '......   json string goes here ......';
2. Now use json_decode PHP function.

   $resultdata = json_decode($jsondata);

The result will be collection of arrays and objects.

However, your data is not is json but serialized so you will need to use  [unserialize](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)

Comment: Thanks bro, but I haven't get success in that function.... I am getting null value by this function.... :(

Comment: anyways How did you got this data?

Answer (score 1):

try json_decode()

refer [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks bro, but I haven't get success in that function.... I am getting null value by this function.... :(

Comment: just check it using var_dump(json_decode($json)); may be its returning objects.try json_decode($json, true); for array

Comment: Can you please specify how your json string is generated

Comment: I don't know actually I am new in oops in php.... I am very much confused for this one.... :(

Comment: that's ok,did you tried unserialize() on that string?